# GAE Python how to get string from user.email()

Tags: python, string, google-app-engine, email

I tried the following in GAE Python to get the string of the user's email-id that I want to store later:

`emailstr = (str(user.email()))`

But the app won't run.

How to get string representation of the user.email()?

I saw [this documentation of User class at GAE doc site](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass#User), but couldn't find the needed info there.

Comment: Does it generate an error? Any stacktrace in the logs? `user.email()` should already be returning a string. So `emailstr = user.email()` should be all you need.

Comment: @aychedee Thanks. I had just seen the GAE logs. I saw it, and got the reason for the error and could correct it. Upvoting your comment just to remind newcomers to see the logs.